# Carbon - Dates are in ISO8601 format with offset notation

Tags: php, php-carbon

I need to convert a user given datetime with format  `Y-m-d H:i:s` to ISO8601 format with offset notation using Php Carbon . The required timezone is Europe/Berlin.

What I have tried so far is

```
     $from = '2021-05-01 00:00:00';
     $dateF = Carbon::createFromDate($from)->tz('Europe/Berlin')->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:sP');
```

And I got the result which is almost what I wanted

```
     2021-05-01T02:00:00+02:00
```

What I actually need is the accurate h:i:s

```
     2021-05-01T00:00:00+02:00
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: createFromDate is not correct, whatever the initial time is, you'll loose it and get current time instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful you need `H` instead of `h` for 0-23 hour.
And you just have to use parse and include the timezone of your date in it to make Carbon aware of the timezone in which the date-time must be read:

```
$from = '2021-05-01 00:00:00';
echo Carbon::parse("$from Europe/Berlin")->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
```

`createFromDate` is not good if you care about the hour/minute/second in your `$from` variable, as it returns only the date you pass with current time.